# yum -y install syslinux' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker

This is my partial docker code, While building my application It is throwing error

```
 RUN yum update –y
    RUN yum -y install syslinux
    RUN yum -y install hostname
    RUN yum -y install net-tools
```

This is my error

```
Total                                              4.2 MB/s | 1.2 MB  00:00     
Retrieving key from https://wwwin-repomgmt.cisco.com/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release7
[91mImporting GPG key 0xFD431D51:
 Userid     : "Red Hat, Inc. (release key 2) <security@redhat.com>"
 Fingerprint: 567e 347a d004 4ade 55ba 8a5f 199e 2f91 fd43 1d51
 From       : https://wwwin-repomgmt.cisco.com/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release7
[0m[91mImporting GPG key 0x2FA658E0:
 Userid     : "Red Hat, Inc. (auxiliary key) <security@redhat.com>"
 Fingerprint: 43a6 e49c 4a38 f4be 9abf 2a53 4568 9c88 2fa6 58e0
 From       : https://wwwin-repomgmt.cisco.com/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release7
[0mRetrieving key from https://wwwin-repomgmt.cisco.com/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta7
[91m

GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install syslinux' returned a non-zero code: 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Performing Post build task...
Match found for : : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : #!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Either try to import the key manually cause it seems that it's not updated.                                          Alternatively you can run yum install --nogpgcheck {packagename}

Comment: Can you provide entire `dockerfile` or atleast the base image `FROM` statement